# filter multiple fields using single input in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a JSON object which is as follows

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Jennifer",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "Aniston",
    "address": "New York City",
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Angelina",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "Jolie",
    "address": "Beverley Hills",
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "Emma",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "Watson",
    "address": "London",
}]
```

I'm populating this data in view using ng-repeat.

```
<td ng-repeat="row in list | filter:filterBeauties">
{{row.firstName}} {{row.lastName}}
</td>
```

Now I have an input box which I'd like to use to filter these names. I would like to use same input box to filter firstName and then filter lastName and don't filter anything else (eg. address).

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="filterBeauties.firstName">
```

Any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: (firstName and lastName)
or would you like
(firstName or lastName)

Comment: firstName and lastName. So if I type Jennifer Aniston in input box it must filter to Jennifer Aniston .

Comment: ok, i think this can only be done by writing a custom filter - because you need to parse the input query parameter...

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but from an architecture standpoint, I would suggest having firstAndLastName in your view and have your search model be on that.

Comment: @ChrisStory you mean I should change backend?

Comment: Yes.  You clearly want your view to do something else.  You can make a method for this to return the JSON array to you differently.  I am working on your custom filter now though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay So this is what I did to solve it.

I added a new item in json object (using [angular.forEach](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function) and filtered by it.

```
$scope.list = beauties.query(function(response) {
    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
          var fullName = value.firstName + ' ' + value.lastName;
          $scope.list[key].fullName = fullName;
   });
});
```

input box code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="filterBeauties.fullName">
```

ng-repeat

```
<td ng-repeat="row in list | filter:filterBeauties">
{{row.firstName}} {{row.lastName}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qa98r/2/).

Essentially, I created a sub-structure for filtering within the data structure being displayed and filter only on that property (e.g. 'filterTerms'):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="search.filterTerms">
   <table border="1">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in list | filter:search">
         <td>{{row.firstName}} {{row.lastName}}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.list = [{
    "id": 1,
    "address": "New York City",
    "firstName": "Jennifer",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "Aniston",
    "filterTerms": {
        "firstName": "Jennifer",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "Aniston",
    }
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "address": "New York City",
    "firstName": "Jennifer",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "Leela",
    "filterTerms": {
        "firstName": "Jennifer",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "Leela",            
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "address": "Beverley Hills",
    "firstName": "Angelina",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "Jolie",
    "filterTerms": {
        "firstName": "Angelina",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "Jolie",            
    }
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "address": "London",
    "firstName": "Emma",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "Watson",
    "filterTerms": {
        "firstName": "Emma",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "Watson",            
    }
}];
}
```

You could simplify this even further for this case by putting all the names into one field (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VsdR3/1/):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.filterTerm" />
    <table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in list | filter:search">
            <td>{{row.first}} {{row.last}} {{row.address}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        "id": 0, "first": "Jenny", "last": "Sorenson", "address": "123 W. Wallnut St.",
        "filterTerm": "Jenny Sorenson"
    },{
        "id": 0, "first": "Susan", "last": "Hinkle", "address": "456 W. Doorbell Dr.",
        "filterTerm": "Susan Hinkle"
    },{
        "id": 0, "first": "Rachel", "last": "Karlyle", "address": "789 W. Sunset Blvd.",
        "filterTerm": "Rachel Karlyle"
    },{
        "id": 0, "first": "Gwen", "last": "Lippi", "address": "0 W. Silly Cir.",
        "filterTerm": "Gwen Lippi"
    }]
}
```

Comment: its like creating an `index` for the list.  good idea.  thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Considering that your user have this form:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Angelina",
  "middleName": null,
  "lastName": "Jolie",
  "address": "Beverley Hills"
}
```

If you want to search one of your user by his firstname, his lastname or both at the same time, you need to concat them together.

```
$scope.query = '';

$scope.search = function (user) {
  var query = $scope.query.toLowerCase(),
  fullname = user.firstName.toLowerCase() + ' ' + user.lastName.toLowerCase();

  if (fullname.indexOf(query) != -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

This function will return `true` if the current user satisfies your query and `false` if not. Inside of the function, I recommend to put your query in lowercases so you won't have to deal with the uppercases your user will enter in the search input.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query">
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">
      <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This technic will only work if you try to search `Angelina Jolie`, `Angelina`, `Jolie` or even `InA JOLIe` (why not after all). If you try to search first the lastname like `Jolie Angelina`, it won't work. You can easily fix it by creating a second fullname in your function (e.g. a `reverseFullname`), concat in first the lastName and then the firstName and test it just like the first fullname string.

Comment: Here is the Plunker for the above solution [https://plnkr.co/edit/eGSMxheRdEUwHzdwRsTu?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/eGSMxheRdEUwHzdwRsTu?p=preview)
OR try this [Plunker][https://plnkr.co/edit/eGSMxheRdEUwHzdwRsTu?p=preview]

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the third argument to the filter function:

```
$filter('filter')(list, {'firstName':search});
```

I would have done something like below:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in list | filterBoth:search">
        <td>{{row.firstName}} {{row.lastName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then write the custom filter as:

```
myApp.filter('filterBoth', function($filter) {
  return function(list, search) {
    if (!search) return list;

    var arrSearch = search.split(' '),
        lookup = '',
        result = [];

    arrSearch.forEach(function(item) {
      lookup = $filter('filter')(list, {'firstName': item});console.log(lookup);
      if (lookup.length > 0) result = result.concat(lookup);
    });

    return result;
  };
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wAp4S/1/

The only issue is you will get duplicate rows as you are concatenating two similar arrays which can easily be fixed using `_.uniq` underscore.js method.

Comment: Hi the jsFiddle you shared doesnt really work the way I want it to. If you write "Jennifer Aniston" in input box it doesnt return anything in result.

Comment: Oh. In that case, you have to split the search by space, filter each word separately, group the result, make it unique, and finally update the scope. The current demo is good enough for you to go ahead and explore it as per your expectation.

Comment: This is not working. Check your jsfiddle. If I type `Ang` I can only see `Angelina` not `Aniston`.

Comment: I don't think 'Ang' should match 'Aniston'.  However, 'An' also does NOT return 'Aniston'.  It appears last names are not being filtered in the fiddle.

Comment: This does not really work the way it should. It also filters on the address, even though this is not the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `angular-filter` library instead of writing *complex filters*.  The `searchField` filter can be helpful here.

https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.users = [
  { first_name: 'Sharon', last_name: 'Melendez' },
  { first_name: 'Edmundo', last_name: 'Hepler' },
  { first_name: 'Marsha', last_name: 'Letourneau' }
];
```

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="search" placeholder="search by full name"/>
<th ng-repeat="user in users | searchField: 'first_name': 'last_name' | filter: search">
  {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
</th>
<!-- so now you can search by full name -->
```

Good Luck.