# Filter ng-repeat based on search input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have the following html:

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="userSearch.firstname">
    </div>
  </div>

 <div>
   <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userSearch ">
     <div>
       {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

So I have an input field where the users can type and search in my list of all users.  Is there a way I can apply a filter inline in the ng-repeat based on what the user types in the search input?

Current solution only filters on firstname

I would like to filter on both first and last name

Tried:

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="userSearch">
    </div>
  </div>

 <div>
   <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{firstname: userSearch, lastname: userSearch} ">
     <div>
       {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

But I think that is an AND not an or.

Comment: Did you look at the [filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js ng-repeat :filter by single field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

Comment: I want to filter on first and last name, sorry should have been more clear.

Comment: Yes @PSL I did look at docs.  Angular docs leave a lot to be desired.  Regardless I am really confused on how to apply this filter.

Comment: Ok got it but then i marked wrong dupilcate :). Here one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs. Exact scenario as [yours here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977703/filter-multiple-fields-using-single-input-in-angularjs)

Comment: @lostintranslation: How can we search for firstname or last name?

Answer (score 13):

Change ng-model from `userSearch.firstname` to just `userSearch`.

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="userSearch">
```

http://jsbin.com/keyuno/1/edit?html,js,output

Alternatively you could change `filter:userSearch` to `filter:userSearch.firstname`. You just need to be sure the filter matches the model.

Comment: Hmm, yes this seems to apply the OR that I am looking for when searching for first or last name.

Comment: Your solution does not seem to filter on the search first <space> last.  Which makes sense.  Is that possible with this data model?

Comment: I believe you'd need to write a custom filter that would return true if it matched either firstname, lastname, or firstname + " " + lastname.

Comment: alternative is more precise