# How I can create a separate scope of data and their applied filter? angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m practicing AngularJS and I’m trying to do a reusable component, 
Until this step, I created it with the directive method, and my doubt is:

How I can separate the data set to json call to the server? ($http.get)

How I can filter the current control with the input text?

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive('list', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      list: '=set'
    },
    replace: true,
    controller: function() {},
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template: layout
  }
});

// template (html)
var layout = '<div>'+
'<input type="text" placeholder="filter" />'+
'<ul>'+
  '<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list">' +
    '<input type="checkbox" /><label>{{item.name}}</label>'+
  '</li>'+
'</ul></div>';
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  maring:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

ul > li {
  background-color:SkyBlue;
  width:200px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width:220px;
  height: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <h2>List 1</h2>
  <list data-set="[{name:'Sergio'},{name:'Maria'}]"></list>
  <h2>List 2</h2>
  <list data-set="[{name:'Agustin'},{name:'Ana'}]"></list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get users from an API just create a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services) that returns your data.

```
app.service('userService', function($http) {
  this.getUser = function() {
    return $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').then(function(list) {
      return list.data.results;
    });
  }
});
```

Inject this service inside the directive.

```
app.directive('list', function(userService)
```

Save the results in a variable inside the link function.

```
link: function (scope)
```

To filter the list you can use a filter like in the posts below

[Filter ng-repeat based on search input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080166/filter-ng-repeat-based-on-search-input)

[ng-repeat :filter by single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

[Filtering by Multiple Specific Model Properties in AngularJS (in OR relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship)

Or simply display the li element if the name contains the string that you write in the input (see snippet below)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive('list', function(userService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    template: layout,
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.users = [];
      userService.getUser().then(function(users) {
        scope.users.push({name: users[0].name.first});
      });
    }
  }
});

var layout = '<div>'+
'<input type="text" placeholder="filter" ng-model="userSearch">'+
'<ul>'+
  '<li ng-repeat="item in users" ng-if="item.name.indexOf(userSearch)>-1 || userSearch.length==0 || userSearch==undefined">' +
    '<input type="checkbox"><label>{{item.name}}</label>'+
  '</li>'+
'</ul></div>';

app.service('userService', function($http) {
  this.getUser = function() {
    return $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').then(function(list) {
      return list.data.results;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  maring:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

ul > li {
  background-color:SkyBlue;
  width:200px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width:220px;
  height: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <h2>List 1</h2>
  <list></list>
  <h2>List 2</h2>
  <list></list>
</div>
```